# How did Moses know he'll spend 40 days at the mountain?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, moshe-rabbeinu, parashat-ki-tisa, golden-calf-egel

As we all know the Golden Calf started with Moses coming up the mountain to learn with Hashem ([Ex 24,17](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.24.17?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)):

> וַיֹּאמֶר ה' אֶל־מֹשֶׁה עֲלֵה אֵלַי הָהָרָה וֶהְיֵה־שָׁם וְאֶתְּנָה לְךָ אֶת־לֻחֹת הָאֶבֶן וְהַתּוֹרָה וְהַמִּצְוָה אֲשֶׁר כָּתַבְתִּי לְהוֹרֹתָם׃ וַיָּקָם מֹשֶׁה וִיהוֹשֻׁעַ מְשָׁרְתוֹ וַיַּעַל מֹשֶׁה אֶל־הַר הָאֱלֹהִים׃ ...
>
> וַיָּבֹא מֹשֶׁה בְּתוֹךְ הֶעָנָן וַיַּעַל אֶל־הָהָר וַיְהִי מֹשֶׁה בָּהָר אַרְבָּעִים יוֹם וְאַרְבָּעִים לָיְלָה׃

Two Parshios later Rashi (where did he learn it from?) [claims Moses told everybody he'll be back after 40 days](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.32.1?lang=he&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Exodus.32.1.1&lang2=he&w2=Shabbat&lang3=he):

> כִּי כְּשֶׁעָלָה מֹשֶׁה לָהָר אָמַר לָהֶם לְסוֹף אַרְבָּעִים יוֹם אֲנִי בָא בְּתוֹךְ שֵׁשׁ שָׁעוֹת

How did he know he will return in exactly 40 days?

Comment: can we assume God told him? Not every single detail that happened was written in the Torah

Comment: @larry909 This is a crucial point of the plot. Without it, Moses being late seems meaningless.

Comment: He did tell the Jews that he will return in 40 days, and we can safely assume that God told him that and that's why he told it to the Jews. No one believes Moshe makes stuff up.
 ודִבֶּ֨ר יְהֹוָ֤ה אֶל־משֶׁה֙ פָּנִ֣ים אֶל־פָּנִ֔ים כַּֽאֲשֶׁ֛ר יְדַבֵּ֥ר אִ֖יש אֶל־רֵעֵ֑הוּ 
  Not every single detail of what transpires is written in the Torah, including many important laws.